# Mysql select join using where clause

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, where-clause

I have 3 tables and select them using left join. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books AS b
LEFT JOIN publisher AS p ON p.publisher_id = b.publisher_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id
WHERE b.cat_id =  '1' // I change value 1, 2, 3, etc, no difference
```

I test that query on Php MyAdmin, no rows appear. But when I remove the "where clause", all rows can be seen. I cannot see the mistake I have made. Please give me a guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `1` without quotes?

Comment: yes, I did. Without quotes, with double quotes, change the b.cat_id to c.category_name and fill value with the name of category, all those are the same

Comment: Integer. Cat_id is a primary key from Category

Comment: If you want to filter based on `category` `cat_id` then shouldn't it be `c.cat_id =  1` since `c` is alias for `category`?

Comment: it will be great if you can share the table's structure as well.

Comment: I'm very sure. I put 5 records in `books` which contain 3 categories. Therefore I try to call the first category in `WHERE b.cat_id='1'`

Comment: Here my table structure: `book_id int(10) Primary Key Auto_Increment
publisher_id int(10)
cat_id int(10)
title varchar (100)
.....
created_at timestamp`

Comment: are you getting any results if you remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: yes, I can retrieve 5 records if I remve WHERE clause

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Show us input without `where`.